# Заполнить матрицу, зная сумму по строке и по столбцу

Tags: python, массивы, pandas, numpy, матрицы

Всем привет!
Есть задача заполнить матрицу MxN рандомными целыми значениями от a до b.
Затык в том, что по каждой строке и по каждому столбцу есть фиксированная сумма. И надо, чтобы эти вот рандомные значения в сумме давали эти числа.

Пробовал выехать на рандоме (цикл выбрал с ограничением, чтобы не работал слишком долго):

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np

stolbcov = 3
strok = 3
massiv = np.zeros(shape=(strok,stolbcov), dtype=int) #создаю нулевой массив
summy_strok = np.array([10,12,6]) #Указываю суммы по каждой строке 
summy_stolbcov = np.array([10,11,7]) #Указываю суммы по каждому столбцу 


#беру функцию, которая дает мне строку данных с нужной суммой
def create_array(n, b):
  for i in range(100):
    a = np.random.randint(0,6,n)
    sum = np.sum(a)
    if sum == b:
      return(a)
      break
  else:
    return(np.random.randint(0,6,stolbcov)) #возвращаем рандомную строку, если не получилось


#в цикле построчно заполняю матрицу. В конце итерации проверяю совпадение по сумме стобцов
for i in range(1000):
  for x in range(strok):
    massiv[x] = create_array(stolbcov,summy_strok[x])
  if np.array_equal(np.sum(massiv, axis=0), summy_stolbcov):
    print(massiv)
    break
```

Проблема в том, что он отрабатывает на небольших матрицах 4х4 ещё приемлемо решает. Дальше уже задумывается надолго.

Пробовал просто рандомно создавать массивы нужной размерности стандартной функцией numpy. Сравнивая суммы в итоге. Этот вариант оказался вообще провальным. Даже 3х3 решить не может.

Может быть, кто знает нормальный алгоритм решения такой задачи без такого вот наглого рандома? Тут больше матан, чем программирование, но буду признателен, если натолкнете на мысль.

Comment: Насколько случайная матрица вам нужна? Она должна "выглядеть случайной"? (слабое требование) Или важно чтобы вероятность получить любую возможную матрицу была одинаковой? (сильное требование)

Answer (score 1):

Такие задачи обычно решаются методом поиска с возвратом. Но, по сути, это тоже перебор значений, хотя и оптимизированный. например, есть библиотека [python-constraint](https://pypi.org/project/python-constraint/), которая может решать такого типа задачи просто задав входные значения и наложив на них ограничения. Но её скорость тоже оставляет желать лучшего.
Пример:

```
from constraint import *
from random import shuffle

summy_strok = [14, 16, 12, 20, 15] #Указываю суммы по каждой строке 
summy_stolbcov = [16, 15, 21, 25] #Указываю суммы по каждому столбцу 
assert sum(summy_strok) == sum(summy_stolbcov)
stolbcov = len(summy_stolbcov)
strok = len(summy_strok)
a, b = 1, 9
values = list(range(a, b+1))
shuffle(values)
#print(values)

problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables(range(strok*stolbcov), values)

for col in range(stolbcov):
    v = [col + stolbcov*row for row in range(strok)]
    problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(summy_stolbcov[col]), v)

for row in range(strok):
    v = [col + stolbcov*row for col in range(stolbcov)]
    problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(summy_strok[row]), v)

solution = problem.getSolution()
result = [v for k,v in sorted(solution.items())]
print(*[result[i:i+stolbcov] for i in range(0, strok*stolbcov, stolbcov)], sep="\n")
```

Результат:

```
[8, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 8, 2, 4]
[3, 2, 6, 1]
[2, 2, 7, 9]
[1, 1, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае ваша задача не имеет решения, даже в вещественных, а не целых числах.

Задачу можно сформулировать так. Есть `M*N` неизвестных, `M+N` уравнений: `M` уравнений для строк и `N` уравнений для столбцов. Нужно найти решение такой недоопределённой системы уравнений.

Если переменные упорядочены слева направо сверху вниз, то элемент матрицы, стоящий в строке `r` и столбце `c` будет иметь номер `r*N + c`. Тогда матрица системы уравнений будет выглядеть как-то так

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

(пример для случая `2 x 3`).

Такие системы проще всего "решать" методом наименьших квадратов, который найдёт такое значение `x`, что `|Ax - B|` будет минимальным. Если у системы есть решение, то минимум достигается именно в нём. Слово "решать" взято в кавычки, так как в общем случае минимум совсем не обязательно равен нулю. Другими словами, решение задачи наименьших квадратов вовсе необязательно является решением исходной системы.

[Я попробовал решить](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19GJO5pFfU7UrQoNtRWJAayaSTitJUl0W?usp=sharing) вашу задачу для случая матрицы `2 x 3`, переменные от 1 до 5, сумма по строкам 7, сумма по столбцам 5.

По ссылке лежит блокнот Jupyter с решением средствами `numpy` и `scipy`. Наименьшие квадраты глобальный минимум нашли, но он даже близко не является решением. То есть такая система решений не имеет. В вещественных числах не имеет, не говоря уже о целых.

Comment: Суммы сумм по строкам и столбцам должны совпадать (с полной суммой матрицы).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy действительно!